# Objects are not valid as a React child using BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have two components and I'm trying to route to /login the first thing that happens if not signed in. I got help with that code here on SO but I'm getting a Objects are not valid as a React child when doing so.

```
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <main>

      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            state,
            dispatch
        }}
      >
      </AuthContext.Provider>

      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/gallery" component={GetPhotos} />
            <Route component={Error} />
            <Route exact path="/">
              {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Redirect to="/gallery" />}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Stack trace:

> > 1638 | react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.render( /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.StrictMode, {
> > |                                                  ^  1639 |   children: /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["BrowserRouter"], {
> > 1640 |     children: /*#**PURE***/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["jsxDEV"])(*components_App__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_["default"], {}, void 0, false, {
> > 1641 |       fileName: _jsxFileName,

Imports:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Login:

```
import React from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./App";
export const Login = () => {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const initialState = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    isSubmitting: false,
    errorMessage: null
  };
const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialState);
const handleInputChange = event => {
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData({
      ...data,
      isSubmitting: true,
      errorMessage: null
    });
    
    fetch("https://api.myurl.nu/login", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password
      })
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        throw res;
      })
      .then(resJson => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: resJson
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setData({
          ...data,
          isSubmitting: false,
          errorMessage: error.message || error.statusText
        });
      });
  };
return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="container">
          <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <h1>Login</h1>

            <label htmlFor="email">
              Email Address
              <input
                type="text"
                value={data.email}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                name="email"
                id="email"
              />
            </label>

            <label htmlFor="password">
              Password
              <input
                type="password"
                value={data.password}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                name="password"
                id="password"
              />
            </label>

            {data.errorMessage && (
              <span className="form-error">{data.errorMessage}</span>
            )}

           <button disabled={data.isSubmitting}>
              {data.isSubmitting ? (
                "Loading..."
              ) : (
                "Login"
              )}
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

GetPhotos import:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import loadingCloud from '../photos/loadingcloud.gif';
import SelectedImage from "./SelectImage";
import Selecto from "react-selecto";
import MenuAppBar from "./Header";
```

App imports

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./Login";
import Header from "./Header";
import GetPhotos from './Photos';
import './App.css';
import reducer from "./Reducer";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  email: null,
  token: null,
};
```

Comment: post the stacktrace, everything looks ok here in terms of that error

Comment: I have added the what I believe is the stack trace, is that correct?

Comment: can you post up the Login and GetPhotos component, everything looks fine here

Comment: Maybe also post the `import` lines to make sure you're correctly importing the relevant components.

Comment: you could probably remove the `AuthContext.Provider` in the meantime, its not doing anything

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I have added the imports and the login component. GetPhotos is too large to post here. Let me know if you see anything wrong in the import or login

Comment: We need to see imports of Login, GetPhotos and app folder files tree

Comment: Sure, I have added the imports for App and GetPhotos as well